# why does bash 'read' expand a wildcard appearing in stdin to yield a directory listing?

Tags: bash, wildcard, stdin

I'm writing a script to process a data file, and started with these two command lines:

```
proc(){ echo $1 ; }

while read -r line ; do proc "$line";  done <data.csv | less
```

To my surprise, I found a listing of the current directory in the middle of the output, and realised it appears where the data file contains an asterisk character.

The expansion occurs before *proc* is called.  Could someone please explain why this is happening.  Is it happening in the command line processor or *read* or the file stream?

I can do this:

```
cat data.csv | tr '*' '_' | while read -r line ; do proc "$line";  done | less
```

but I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent this expansion.

Alternatively, is there a way to filter input using the redirection form, rather than the pipe, and what other special characters, eg: *[,],?,-* would I need to replace?

Cheers,
bitrat

PS: An example data file:

```
gfh fg hfgh fgh fg hgh 
7 4 674 547767 56 7 56756
ghdghh gh fg h fgh fg hf gh
8 678 678 * 67 867 8 678 
gfh fg hfgh fgh fg hgh 
7 4 674 547767 56 7 56756
ghdghh gh fg h fgh fg hf gh
8 678 678 67 867 8 678
```

And example output:

```
gfh fg hfgh fgh fg hgh
7 4 674 547767 56 7 56756
ghdghh gh fg h fgh fg hf gh
8 678 678 data.csv file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt  67 867 8 678
gfh fg hfgh fgh fg hgh
7 4 674 547767 56 7 56756
ghdghh gh fg h fgh fg hf gh
8 678 678 67 867 8 678
```

UPDATE:

The asterisk is only treated as a wildcard if it has spaces on either side, so must be getting tokenised at some point.

UPDATE2:

The expansion doesn't occur if echo is called directly..

```
while read -r line ; do echo "$line";  done <data.csv
```

Comment: An asterisk expands to a directory listing.  I don't think it matters what else is in the data a file, but I've added an example.  :-)

Comment: What did http://shellcheck.net tell you about your script? As the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag you used says - `For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here`.

Comment: `$ shellcheck myscript
No issues detected!`

Comment: shellcheck *definitely* detects the unquoted expansion as a bug. Just a minute and I'll link to it running.

Comment: Thanks for shellcheck.net  Handy to know.  Yes, it does detect the quotes, thanks!  For some reason I typed the variable in quotes there and not on my command line...

Comment: https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/LittleQuarrelsomeIntelligence -- wherein shellcheck emits the following warning: `SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.` (relevant wiki page @ https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086) -- if you can fork that and link me to a repl where it _isn't_ detected, I'll be interested to see it (and glad to analyze for why it didn't flag in whichever case is given).

Comment: Regarding `The asterisk is only treated as a wildcard if it has spaces on either side` - no, it just didn't match anything. `*` matches any string, `*foo` just matches strings that end in `foo` so apparently you don't have any files in your directory that end in whatever string is concatenated to the end of `*` in your input.

Comment: Regarding `The expansion doesn't occur if echo is called directly..` - no, the problem has nothing to do with echo being called directly vs inside a function, it's entirely about your lack of quotes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why: Pathname expansion happens later than variable expansion. Search for "order of expansions" in `man bash`.

The expansion does **not** occur before *proc* is called, it happens inside *proc*.

Solution: Add double quotes:

```
echo "$1"
```